# How to send many byte[] arrays with HttpClient in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have WebApi application with method signature below:

```
        [HttpGet("VerifySignature")]
        public VerifySignatureResult VerifySignature(byte[] file, byte[] signature)
        {
            return new VerifySignatureResult() { Verified = true };
        }
```

I need to make request to this method from another WebApi (I don't think application type matters, it can be a simple console). I can move two byte arrays into single class for convenience, but I don't want to make them IFormFile.
How can I achieve this with HttpClient?

Comment: It has to be a POST request and you could put both byte arrays as properties into a json object within the body.

Comment: Just a comment to your choosen names. To verify a signature of a file you normally don't send the whole file and signature to a server. Instead you would ask the server for the public key, decrypt the signature with it, compute the hash of file and compare that self computed hash with the given decrypted signature hash. If both are the same, the file wasn't tampered and you don't have to send GBs of files for verification to your server.

Comment: @Oliver It's not PKI infrastructure, it's inside enterprize decisions

Comment: I found solution in changing byte[] to IFormFile